# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined at draw (sketch.js:49)

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js, google-chrome-console

I am specifying the function show() inside the function Spot() but still I am getting this error of Uncaught TypeError and its saying its undefined at draw().

This is the Javascript code and I am using p5.js as library.

```js
var cols = 5;
rows = 5;
var grid = new Array(cols);

var w,h;

function Spot(i,j){
    this.x = i;
    this.y = j;
    this.f = 0;
    this.g = 0;
    this.h = 0;

    this.show = function(){
        fill(255);
        stroke(0);
        rect(this.x*w,this.y*h,w-1,h-1);
    }  
}

function setup(){
    createCanvas(400,400);
    console.log('A*');

    w = width/cols;
    h = height/rows;

    for(var i = 0; i < cols;i++){
        grid[i] = new Array(rows);
    }

    console.log(grid);
    
    for(var i = 0; i < cols;i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; i < rows;i++)
        {
            grid[i][j] = new Spot(i,j);
        }
    }
}
function draw(){
    background(0);
    
    for(var i = 0; i < cols-1;i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < rows-1; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j].show();
        }
    }
}
```

```css
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sketch.js/1.1/sketch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js"></script>
```

I am getting this error in chrome console and i am running the html as a web server on my local pc.(localhost:8000)

This is the attached image for the error in google chrome console

[image]

I have just started with java script and not able to resolve this error despite extensive searching about it.

It would be helpful if someone knows about it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Aniket, its really helpful if your snippet can run in the browser. Use the snippet function here at SO to include a "running/failing" version of your code. You can include scripts from CDNs.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in your setup loop.

In the nested loop, you are increasing the `i` value, instead of the `j` value.

And your also counting the rows/columns indexes different in the `setup` and `draw`.
This might be what you want, just thought I would point it out.

( `rows/cols-1` vs `cols/rows`)

```js
var cols = 5;
var rows = 5;
var grid = new Array(cols);

var w,h;

function Spot(i,j){
    this.x = i;
    this.y = j;
    this.f = 0;
    this.g = 0;
    this.h = 0;

    this.show = function(){
        fill(255);
        stroke(0);
        rect(this.x*w,this.y*h,w-1,h-1);
    }
}

function setup(){
    createCanvas(400,400);
    console.log('A*');

    w = width/cols;
    h = height/rows;

    for(var i = 0; i < cols;i++){
        grid[i] = new Array(rows);
    }

    console.log('grid: ', grid);
    
    for(var i = 0; i < cols-1;i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < rows-1;j++)
        {
            grid[i][j] = new Spot(i,j);
        }
    }
}
function draw(){
    background(0);
    
    for(var i = 0; i < cols-1;i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < rows-1; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j].show();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sketch.js/1.1/sketch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: BTW Christer, does Uncaught TypeError mean a typo only/Logical syntax wrong right ?

Comment: The simple answer would be "yes". Accessing properties that doesnt exist because of typos or logical errors that doesnt assign the property correctly.